# python re: need help creating a pattern

Tags: python, regex

Quick silly question...
I am trying to create a pattern to match the following type of string `'12/06/06 08:15'`.

I tried `r'/d{1-2}///d{1-2}///d{1-2} /d{1-2}:/d{1-2}'` and `'/d{1-2}///d{1-2}///d{1-2} /d{1-2}:/d{1-2}'` but obviously it doesnt work... Can anyone give me a leg up?

Comment: Why not use a datetime lib? See [doc links on this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/466376/868044)

Comment: @Dan because some of the strings i want to test don't correspond to that format. That's precisely the goal, i.e. separate strings that match from those which don't

Comment: `/` is not the same as `\\`.

Comment: `-` is not the same as `,`.

Comment: @Radar Does error handling work? If the string format is different from the one you specify in your `datetime.strptime()` it will throw a `ValueError`.

Comment: @Dan How would you do error handling? For instance if one of the string encountered is `'30/06/06-01/07/06'` - (this is the error in the current state of affairs..)

Comment: @Radar if you get an exception (try...except), then try next most common pattern (e.g. day/month/year), if still an exception, write the line number out to an exceptions file and review those to see if there is a pattern.

Comment: But if you're using pandas (which was not stated in your original question), you can use something like `pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', errors='raise')` to raise an exception then try parsing again with `to_datetime()` using `format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'`. You can experiment with `errors='coerce'` and `ignore` also. [See the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html). Note that pandas use strftime to that documentation is applicable to the format keyword argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for the pattern shown:

```
r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}'
```

But this really should be done with a datetime lib and just handle exceptions for non-matching lines.

- Python documentation for `strptime`: [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)
- Python documentation for `strftime` format mask: [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)
- [Good strftime reference](http://strftime.org/)

Comment: Sorry, I was using grep for testing, and forward slashes do mean something in grep. I suppose this is not true of Python.

Comment: No, grep doesn't care about `/` either.

Comment: @Dan Hmm ok. Yeah its true i was using the pandas `to_datetime()` and not the `strptime` or `strftime`. I will look into that. Thx!

Comment: @Dan regexr.com uses your browser's JavaScript regex engine (JavaScript uses slashes to delimit regex literals in its syntax, but they're not part of the regex per se; they work like `"` does for strings). It doesn't have anything to do with grep.

Comment: @melpomene good to know. Next time I'll be sure to fire up a python interpreter instead. Thanks!

Comment: @Dan Yeah I love it. The python code generator sucks - it generates 30 lines where 3 would do. However, the rest of the site is top notch.